# Minecraft 1.6.4 on Windows

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to run 1.6.4 with MultiMC and the official launcher, in both cases the game wouldn't launch, but if I tried to launch it multmc / the official launcher would complain that it was already running. Minecraft 1.6.4 didn't show up in Task Manager, either. Is it simply not possible to run 1.6.4 on Windows anymore?

Comment: I suggest that, either you provide any related information such as crash logs. And it should be, I wouldn't get why Java would refuse to run 1.6.4 specifically. And Minecraft shows up as Java (TM) Binary.

Comment: I went through releases one-by-one and 1.12.2 is the newest release that I can't run, here's a screenshot of the official launcher logs https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/718514902201008231/807679451843919883/unknown.png

Comment: Java version? You might have to downgrade depending on your Java version.

Comment: MultiMC says my java version is 1.8.0_281 64-bit, I'm not sure if that is what the official launcher uses though

Comment: The official launcher uses a seperate java version for various reasons. So you may want to try a different launcher that will use your installed Java version, such as TLauncher.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! I'm not sure why this fixed it but I restarted my PC, deleted `.minecraft`, and now 1.6.4 starts up just fine.